# Exit delay animation in react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-transition-group

I am using **react-transition-group** in a **ReactJS** and **GatsbyJS** (V2) project.

I have my page transitions working with animation but when `Link` exit, the `exiting` animation is cut short because the next page is ready for entering.

I have tried delaying the `Link` action but whilst the page change was delayed, the `exit` animation is not triggered until the `delay` was over and the `Link` was actioned.

How can I `delay` the page change, whilst initiating the `exiting` animation `onClick`? Alternatively, is there a better way or `props` available?

Here is my code

**Layout.js**

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  ...
  return (
    <Transition>{children}</Transition>
  );
}
```

**Transition.js**

```
class Transition extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { exiting: false };
    this.listenerHandler = this.listenerHandler.bind(this);
  }

  listenerHandler() {
    this.setState({ exiting: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener(historyExitingEventType, this.listenerHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener(historyExitingEventType, this.listenerHandler);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps({ exiting }) {
    if (exiting) {
      return { exiting: false };
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    const transitionProps = {
      timeout: {
        enter: 0,
        exit: timeout
      },
      appear: true,
      in: !this.state.exiting
    };

    return (
      <ReactTransition {...transitionProps}>
        {status => (
          <div
            style={{
              ...getTransitionStyle({ status, timeout })
            }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        )}
      </ReactTransition>
    );
  }
}

export default Transition;
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const timeout = 1500;
const historyExitingEventType = `history::exiting`;

const getUserConfirmation = (pathname, callback) => {
  const event = new CustomEvent(historyExitingEventType, {
    detail: { pathname }
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(true);
  }, timeout);
};

let history;
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  history = createHistory({ getUserConfirmation });
  history.block(location => location.pathname);
}

export const replaceHistory = () => history;

export { historyExitingEventType, timeout };
```

**getTransitionStyle.js**

```
const getTransitionStyles = timeout => {

return {
    entering: {
      transform: `scale(1.05) translateZ(0)`,
      opacity: 0
    },
    entered: {
      transition: `transform 750ms ease, opacity ${timeout}ms ease`,
      transitionDelay: `750ms`,
      transform: `scale(1) translateZ(0)`,
      opacity: 1
    },
    exiting: {
      transition: `transform 750ms ease, opacity ${timeout}ms ease`,
      transform: `scale(0.98) translateZ(0)`,
      opacity: 0
    }
  };
};

const getTransitionStyle = ({ timeout, status }) =>
  getTransitionStyles(timeout)[status];

export default getTransitionStyle;
```

Comment: If you're on the latest Gatsby beta this won't work because Gatsby is now using Reach Router instead of react-router. Delaying route transitions isn't supported (yet). I left a comment on this [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5656#issuecomment-411762437).

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchultz. I saw your comment yesterday at the link provided and will look out for a response to the topic. Thank you again - Good to know that someone of your stature in the Gatsby community is looking for a solution.

Comment: @FabianSchultz. I noticed that you have added a solution on the **Gatsby** github that works perfectly to my issue. Thank you for that. I thought if you wanted to answer this question with that solution as to close it, I'll send the bounty your way. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gatsby v2 is using Reach Router instead of React Router, so using `getUserConfirmation` with `replaceHistory` will not work anymore. In the Gatsby v2 RC you can use `react-pose` to create page transitions a little more straightforward:

<sub>**gatsby-browser.js** and **gatsby-ssr.js**:</sub>

```
import React from "react"
import Transition from "./src/components/transition"
 export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <Transition {...props}>{element}</Transition>
}
```

<sub>**transition.js** component:</sub>

```
import React from "react"
import posed, { PoseGroup } from "react-pose"

const timeout = 250

class Transition extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { children, location } = this.props

    const RoutesContainer = posed.div({
      enter: { delay: timeout, delayChildren: timeout },
    })

    // To enable page transitions on mount / initial load,
    // use the prop `animateOnMount={true}` on `PoseGroup`.
    return (
      <PoseGroup>
        <RoutesContainer key={location.pathname}>{children}</RoutesContainer>
      </PoseGroup>
    )
  }
}

export default Transition
```

<sub>Inside your **pages**:</sub>

```
// Use `posed.div` elements anywhere on the pages.

const Transition = posed.div({
  enter: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
})

// ...

<Transition>Hello World!</Transition>
```

---

Check the [official example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-page-transitions) for a working demo.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. It is a great example. Accepted the answer obviously but how do I apply the bounty? It's generally available when I accept an answer.

Comment: I didn't see anything about the question having a bounty. No worries though!

Comment: Looking further the bounty expired, sorry. Was a good one too at 150 - would have put you over the 7k. Anyway, cheers and have a great day.